# What is causing the warning "Unexpected Fiber popped" in my React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings

In a fairly complex application, I made some changes related to `ref`s and suddenly started seeing this warning.

Even though it's a warning, it's breaking my application.

I'm using React 16.3.0 with a next.js backend.

What is causing the "Unexpected Fiber popped" warning?

Answer (score 6):

**This is a bug in React.**

Please [report it with a minimal example](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/new) and we'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

### Update to React `>=16.3.1`

This is a red herring warning which gets thrown when other errors occur.

In my particular case, it was caused by passing a prop to a DOM element which it didn't understand:

```
<div isModalOpen={true}>... Modal contents ...</div>
```

`react@16.3.1` fixes the red herring warning.

Comment: This sounds very weird. Please file a bug if you can reproduce.

Comment: I am still seeing this error on 16.3.1. Started a new react-native app and bumped on this. Let me see if I can find the root cause

Answer (score 1):

I had this error after upgrading React from 16.3.0 to 16.3.1 but forgot to upgrade React-Dom from 16.3.0 to match React. After upgrading both to 16.3.1 the issue was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me when I didn't use `Animated.` prefix in my animated component. For Example If you are animating a `<View>` component, use,

```
<Animated.View>
```

not

```
<View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too. it's so stressing me out but after a while i figured it out that **i used an arrow asynchronous function instead of calling a single function as component** in react <Suspense>. after i refactored it, it solved!

here's my code before:

```
import { must_login } from "./server-utils";

export default async function Dashboard() {

    return(
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading . .</p>}>
            {(async () => {
                await must_login();
                return <></>;
            })()}
        </Suspense>
    };
}
```

and here's after:

```
import MustLogin from "./must-login"

export default async function Dashboard() {

    return(
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading . .</p>}>
            <MustLogin />
        </Suspense>
    };
}
```

here's inside `must-login.tsx`:

```
import { must_login } from "./server-utils";

export async function MustLogin() {
    await must_login();
    return <></>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in React Native. Turned out I had used div instead of View ‍♂️